# Text alignment in html

Tags: html, alignment

how to align text to right or left without using  paragraph tag in HTML

Is there any other tag to do alignment?

Comment: how about using CSS, with text-align:left or right?

Comment: Don't think about using "tags" to do styling. Mark up the information appropriately, style with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any **block container** with `style="text-align: left"` will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any block level element (div for instance) (or force a inline element to behave like a block element with `display: block`). Then style that element with the appropriate CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

Any block tag will do the job as long as you have its style attribute set to `style="text-align:left";` or respectively `style="text-align:right";`

Think about putting this in a stylesheet instead of inline like this.

Lots of people still don't realise that HTML is meant to be semantic and not control how elements are displayed - thats a job for CSS.

Hence your statement:

> Is there any other tag to do
>   alignment?

Is technically incorrect.

Comment: Not any "tag". The text-align property only applies to block containers. The style attribute should be avoided though in favour of proper stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to align the text in *any* (block-level) element.  Specifically, you want the `text-align` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the text with a `<div>` tag, you can give the `<div>` an attribute, for example `style="text-align:left"` or `style="text-align:right` to position your text.

Example:

```
<div style="text-align:left">
    Your text comes here...
</div>
```

You can read a little more about the text-align, but also the style attribute here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Answer (score -1):

Use  `<span class="right">Text here</span>` in your html and add this `.right{text-align:right}` to your css

Comment: This will not work, unless you make SPAN a block element (see my answer).

Comment: Span is, by default, `display: inline` so this is not a *block container* so the text-align property will not apply and this will not have any effect. (And 'right' is a sucky class name).